# Select box not changing after changing the value from redux-devtools

Tags: redux, redux-devtools

locale is in my redux app state. Changing its value through react-devtools (revert option), changes paragraph inner value but not the select box value.
If it renders again shouldn't it take the same value as inside the p tag?

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react'
import {defineMessages, injectIntl, intlShape} from 'react-intl'
const messages = defineMessages({
  spanish: {
    id: 'languageSelector.spanish',
    description: 'Select language',
    defaultMessage: 'Spanish'
  },
  english: {
    id: 'languageSelector.english',
    description: 'Select language',
    defaultMessage: 'English'
  },
  french: {
    id: 'languageSelector.french',
    description: 'Select language',
    defaultMessage: 'French'
  }
})

class LanguageSelector extends Component {
    render () {
      const {formatMessage, locale} = this.props.intl
      return (
        <div>
        <select defaultValue={locale} onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}>
                <option id='es' value='es'>{formatMessage(messages.spanish)}</option>
                <option id='fr' value='fr'>{formatMessage(messages.french)}</option>
                <option id='en' value='en'>{formatMessage(messages.english)}</option>
        </select>
        <p>{locale}</p>
        </div>
        )
    }
    handleChange (e) {
      this.props.onChange(e.target.value)
    }
}

LanguageSelector.propTypes = {
  intl: intlShape.isRequired,
  onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}
export default injectIntl(LanguageSelector)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `defaultValue` to `value`. i.e.

```
<select value={locale} onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}>
```

#### Explanation

You only use `defaultValue` when the form field is an **uncontrolled component**. The only way to change the value of an uncontrolled component is through user input.

If you use `value` then the form component is considered a **controlled component**. Its value can be changed in subsequent renders by setting the value explicitly. Controlled components must also have an `onChange` handler, which yours does.

For more information on controlled/uncontrolled form components, see [Forms in React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html).