# How to properly bind onChange callback to 'this' with ReactJS, Redux, and ES2015?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bind, ecmascript-6, redux

I'm learning ReactJS and Redux, and I cant figure out how to get access to my TextField instance while binding it's onChange callback to `this`.

(I'm using [material-ui](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui) for this example, but I would encounter quite the same problem without it)

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { setDataValue } from './actions/data';
import TextField from 'material-ui/lib/text-field';
import Paper from 'material-ui/lib/paper';

export class DataInput extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    handleTextChange() {
        this.props.setDataValue(document.getElementById('myField').value);
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <Paper style={{
                width: '300px',
                margin: '10px',
                padding: '10px'
            }}>
                <TextField 
                  id='myField'
                  defaultValue={this.props.data.value}
                  onChange={this.handleTextChange.bind(this)} />
            </Paper>
        );
    }
}

export default connect(
  (state) => ({data: state.data}),
  {setDataValue}
)(DataInput);
```

I'm using a solution that I find ugly (not reusable => not very 'component-friendly') by setting an `id` on my TextField, and accessing its value with `document.getElementById('myField').value`

How could I get rid of this `id`, and accessing it with something like `textFieldRef.value` inside my callback ?

I tried without `.bind(this)`, which gives me access to my TextField instance through `this`, but I can no longer access my `this.props.setDataValue()` function since `this` isn't binded to my class context.

Thank you !

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Avoid using calls like `document.getElementById` within a React component. React is already designed to optimise expensive DOM calls, so you're working against the framework by doing this. If you want to know how reference DOM nodes in React, read the docs [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

However, in this situation you don't actually need references. Placing a ref (or an ID) on `TextField` isn't necessarily going to work. What you're referencing is a React element, not a DOM node.

Instead, make better use of the `onChange` callback. The function passed to `onChange` is called with an `event` argument. You can use that argument to get the input value. (see React's [event system](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html).)

Your event handler should look like this:

```
handleTextChange(event) {
    this.props.setDataValue(event.target.value);
}
```

And your `TextField` should look like this:

```
<TextField 
    value={this.props.data.value}
    onChange={event => this.handleTextChange(event)}
/>
```

Note: [Use value NOT defaultValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35011730/select-box-not-changing-after-changing-the-value-from-redux-devtools/35013613#35013613).

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer ! That's it, the event, how could I miss that ?
I'm very aware of using document.getElementById being a very bad practice in React, but I couldn't figure out another solution, hence my question :)
I should have read the material-ui docs more carefully, thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Using state along with Redux is a bad style. So this is a design issue of the code.

Redux was meant to be used along with functional components and not class style ones.

I suggest using functional component and pass syntetic event as a parameter to onChange function like this:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
return {
    onChange: (value) => {
        dispatch(changeAction(value))
    }
}
```

and then use something like this inside the element:

```
<input onChange={ (e) => onChange(e.target.value)}
```

You can also pass elements own properties:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
```

Comment: This line is not correct `Redux was meant to be used along with functional components and not class style ones.` form the redux docs `If and when you need to add local state, lifecycle methods, or performance optimizations, you can convert them to classes.`  -  http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html